# mysql inner join to relate all tuples

Tags: mysql, sql, join, data-retrieval

I have the following tables:

```
copy(movie_id,copy_id)
rented(copy_id,outdate,returndate)
```

If a movie is rented out, the returndate is set to null in the database.

There will be multiple copies of the same movie. for a single movie_id, we can have multiple copy_id.

I need to retrieve the movies that have been rented out completely, i.e. all the copies of the movie have been rented out or put in another way-all the copies of a movie are present in the rented table with the returndate set as null.

I have tried inner joins, but am not being able to relate all the tuples in the copy table to the rented table.

Each copy has a globally unique copy_id. So copies of 2 different movies cannot have the same copy_id.

If the copy has never been rented, it will not show up in the list, however it means that the movie is still in stock, as it has never been rented. This should not show up.

The same movie and copy will definitely appear in rented multiple times, if it has been rented more than once.

Comment: `....GROUP BY movie_ID HAVING SUM(returndate IS NOT NULL)=0`

Comment: .... how do you know what movie was rented?  if 2 different movies each have 2 copies... (copy IDs 1 and 2 for movies A and B) wouldn't copy ID 2 still be missing what movie was rented (is that for A or B movie?) or is copy_Id also a UNIQUE identifier across all movies?  ( such as Movies A & B with copy_ID 1,2,3,4) and never a duplicate copy_ID?

Comment: Additionally if no record exists in rented it just means that copy hasn't ever been rented so movies like this should not show up on your list right?  PUt anotherway, you want a list of movies titles for which no copy is presently in stock...  Could the same movie and copy appear in rented multiple times?  interesting problem...

Comment: Not enough information has been presented to answer this.  We need to know if copy_ID is unique across all movies, if it's not then we have no way to complete the request without an additional field in rented, specifically movie_ID.

Comment: Does @popovitsj or Gordan's approach get the desired result? It seems like they

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out a little bit more difficult than I thought. I believe this is the correct answer.

"All movies, for which for all of its copies there exists a rented where returndate is null"

In mathematical notation (A=for All, E=there exists):

{ m : M | ( A c : C | c.movie_id = m.movie_id @ ( E r : R | r.copy_id = c.copy_id @ r.returndate = null ) ) @ m.movie_id }

Which can be rephrased to:

"All movies, for which there doesn't exist a copy, for which there doesn't exist a rented where returndate is null"

Which translates to the following SQL.

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.movie_id
FROM Copy m
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM Copy c
  WHERE c.movie_id = m.movie_id
  AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM Rented r
    WHERE r.copy_id = c.copy_id
    AND returndate IS NULL)
```

Comment: this will not return movies which have never been rented but which a copy exists.  thus doesn't fit the need of, "retrieve the movies that have been rented out completely, i.e. all the copies of the movie have been rented out."

Comment: Movie A has copies 1 and 2.  Rented table only has a record for Copy 2 listed as Copy 1 has never been rented.  If copy 1 has never been rented it will be excluded by your inner join.  So how can you say all the stores copies are rented if by the nature of your join you're excluding some movies that have never been rented, thus can't be completely rented out.  I'm reading the question as "give me a list of movies which we OWN copies, but none are presently in stock"  Clearly if it's never been rented, it's still in stock.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it's a little bit more intricate than I thought. Please review my edit and see if this now correct.

Comment: This works provided we assume copy_ID is unique across all movies.  If movie A has two Copies Copy ID 1 and 2 and Movie B has two copies also Copy_Id 1 and_2... then this wouldn't work either.  but we don't know until the OP defines that better.

Comment: There's really no reason to think that this is not the case, even if it's not explicitly mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want by using a `left join` and aggregation with a `having` clause.  Then, count the number of records with no return date and compare that to the number of copies:

```
SELECT c.movie_id
FROM copy c LEFT JOIN
     rented r
     ON c.copy_id = r.copy_id
GROUP BY c.movie_id
HAVING SUM(r.returndate IS NULL) = COUNT(DISTINCT c.copy_id)
```

Note the use of `SUM()` for the comparison.  This counts the number of rows where the value is "true".

The above query assumes that a single copy cannot be rented more than once at a time.  A reasonable assumption, but always worth checking.  An alternative `having` clause takes this into account:

```
HAVING count(distinct case when r.returndate is null then c.copy_id end) = count(distinct c.copy_id)
```

Comment: +1 I always enjoy your answers; I learn more creative ways of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by movie_id and count where returndate is null:

```
SELECT DISTINCT movie_id
FROM copy
JOIN rented
ON copy.copy_id = rented.copy_id
GROUP BY copy.movie_id HAVING COUNT(rented.returndate IS NULL) = 0
```

Comment: this will not return movies which have never been rented but which a copy exists. thus doesn't fit the need of, "retrieve the movies that have been rented out completely, i.e. all the copies of the movie have been rented out.

Comment: if the movie has never been rented but copies exist, then clearly it will not be part of the collection of movies that have been rented out completely.

Comment: True, so how does that answer the question of "Retrieve the movies that have been RENTED out COMPLETELY" if you're not including copies that have never been rented?

Comment: Oh, wait... okay, I see what you are saying now. Yeah, that is an interesting problem.